# Como implementar eventos a dieferentes Checkbox

Tags: java-swing, checkbox

hace dias estoy intentando hacer un ejercico de un pagina de pedidos de pizza, en principio el programa funciona porque solo tengo tres opciones para elegir ingredientes extra para la pizza y no son muchas combinaciones. El problema viene si por ejemplo tuviera 15 ingredientes extra, seria una locura de combinaciones posibles. He intentado hacer un metodo con un contador, utilizar bucles pero simpre tengo el mismo problema, que la primera vez si me hace el cambio en el precio total pero a la hora de desmarcar las casillas no me cambia el precio. Tambien en mi programa, con cada if-else tengo q estar sobreescribiendo el label, he intentado ponerlo al final pero cada vez que marco la casilla sigue sumando el ingrediente extra aunque sea el mismo. No se si me he explicado bien, es mi primera pregunta :-) Lo siento pq algunos nombres estan en aleman, pero el ejercicio es para clase y vivo en Alemania, pero ppienso que en rasgos generales se entiende, sino aclaro dudas sobre nombres de variables. Muchas gracias de antemano a todos por vuestras respuestas.
[image: Ventana de Bienvenida[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbcK3.jpg)

```
package clases;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WillkommenMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Kunde kunde1 = new Kunde(1, "Max Smith");
        WillkommenFrame fenster = new WillkommenFrame(kunde1);
        fenster.setVisible(true);
        fenster.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fenster.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

class WillkommenFrame extends JFrame{

    JLabel lab_logo, lab_kndnr,lab_will;
    JPanel panel_kunde, panel_will;
    JButton button_ok;
    JTextField txt_kndnr;

    public WillkommenFrame(Kunde kunde){

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBounds(0,0,450,360);
        setTitle("Call-a-Pizza");

        Toolkit myscreen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image myIcon = myscreen.getImage("src/images/icon_pizza.jpg");
        setIconImage(myIcon);

        // ---------------- Label Logo -----------------

        lab_logo = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        lab_logo.setSize(new Dimension(440, 250));
        ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("src/images/CallaPizza.jpg");
        Icon icono = new ImageIcon(logo.getImage().getScaledInstance(lab_logo.getWidth(),
                lab_logo.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        lab_logo.setIcon(icono);
        add(lab_logo, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // ----------------- Label Willkommen -------------------------

        panel_will = new JPanel();
        panel_will.setBackground(new Color(211,233,240));
        lab_will = new JLabel("¡¡ HERZLICH WILLKOMMEN !!");
        lab_will.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lab_will.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        panel_will.add(lab_will);
        add(panel_will, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // ----------------- Panel Kundennummer -----------------------

        panel_kunde = new JPanel();
        panel_kunde.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel_kunde.setBackground(new Color(211,233,240));
        add(panel_kunde, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        lab_kndnr = new JLabel("Kundennummer   ");
        lab_kndnr.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        txt_kndnr = new JTextField(10);
        txt_kndnr.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        txt_kndnr.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        button_ok = new JButton("OK");
        button_ok.setBackground(new Color(251,241,60));

        panel_kunde.add(lab_kndnr);
        panel_kunde.add(txt_kndnr);
        panel_kunde.add(button_ok);

        // ------------- ButtonListener ---------------------------
        button_ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
                BestellungFrame fenster_bestellung = new BestellungFrame(kunde);
                fenster_bestellung.setVisible(true);
                fenster_bestellung.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                fenster_bestellung.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });
    }
}

class BestellungFrame extends JFrame {

    protected JLabel lab_pizza, lab_zutaten, zutaten1, zutaten2, zutaten3, lab_total,
            bildbehälter1, bildbehälter2, bildbehälter3, lab_preise;
    JPanel panel_zutaten, panel_extra, panel_unten, panel_button, panel_bilder, panel_preis, panel_button1;
    JButton button_bestellen, button_jumbo, button_single, button_big;
    JCheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3;
    Icon bild1, bild2, bild3, single, jumbo, big;
    protected double preis = 11.50;
    protected final double extra = 0.90;

    public BestellungFrame(Kunde kunde) {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBounds(0, 0, 440, 750);
        setTitle("¡Hallo! " + kunde.getName());

        Toolkit myscreen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Image myIcon = myscreen.getImage("src/images/icon_pizza.jpg");
        setIconImage(myIcon);

        // ---------------------- Label Pizza -----------------------------------------

        lab_pizza = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        lab_pizza.setSize(new Dimension(430, 250));
        ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("src/images/pizza.jpg");
        Icon icono = new ImageIcon(logo.getImage().getScaledInstance(lab_pizza.getWidth(),
                lab_pizza.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        lab_pizza.setIcon(icono);
        add(lab_pizza, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // ------------------ Panel Zutaten ---------------------------------------------

        panel_zutaten = new JPanel();
        panel_zutaten.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel_zutaten.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel_zutaten.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Zutaten"));
        add(panel_zutaten, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // ---------------- Panel Botones Precios ----------------------------------------

        BotonListener bL = new BotonListener();
        panel_button1 = new JPanel();
        panel_button1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel_button1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        single = new ImageIcon("src/images/single.jpg");
        button_single = new JButton(single);
        button_single.setActionCommand("single");
        button_single.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(87, 87));
        button_single.addActionListener(bL);
        panel_button1.add(button_single);

        jumbo = new ImageIcon("src/images/jumbo.jpg");
        button_jumbo = new JButton(jumbo);
        button_jumbo.setActionCommand("jumbo");
        button_jumbo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(87, 87));
        button_jumbo.addActionListener(bL);
        panel_button1.add(button_jumbo);

        big = new ImageIcon("src/images/big.jpg");
        button_big = new JButton(big);
        button_big.setActionCommand("big");
        button_big.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(87, 87));
        button_big.addActionListener(bL);
        panel_button1.add(button_big);

        // ---------------------- Panel Zutaten ------------------------------------------

        lab_zutaten = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        lab_zutaten.setSize(new Dimension(420, 120));
        ImageIcon logoZ = new ImageIcon("src/images/zutaten.jpg");
        Icon iconoZ = new ImageIcon(logoZ.getImage().getScaledInstance(lab_zutaten.getWidth(),
                lab_zutaten.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        lab_zutaten.setIcon(iconoZ);

        panel_zutaten.add(panel_button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel_zutaten.add(lab_zutaten, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // --------------------- Panel Extra-Zutaten --------------------------------------

        panel_extra = new JPanel();
        panel_extra.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel_extra.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(panel_extra, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        panel_unten = new JPanel();
        panel_unten.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel_unten.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel_unten.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Wähle Deine Extras je 0,90 €"));
        panel_extra.add(panel_unten, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // --------------- Panel Bilder Extra Zutaten & CheckBox -----------------------------------

        CheckListener cL = new CheckListener();
        panel_bilder = new JPanel();
        panel_bilder.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        panel_bilder.setBackground(new Color(244, 244, 244));

        bild1 = new ImageIcon("src/images/cebolla.jpg");
        bildbehälter1 = new JLabel(bild1);
        zutaten1 = new JLabel("Zwiebel");
        cb1 = new JCheckBox();
        cb1.setBackground(new Color(244, 244, 244));
        cb1.addItemListener(cL);

        bild2 = new ImageIcon("src/images/tomate.jpg");
        bildbehälter2 = new JLabel(bild2);
        zutaten2 = new JLabel("Tomate");
        cb2 = new JCheckBox();
        cb2.setBackground(new Color(244, 244, 244));
        cb2.addItemListener(cL);

        bild3 = new ImageIcon("src/images/jalapenos.jpg");
        bildbehälter3 = new JLabel(bild3);
        zutaten3 = new JLabel("Jalapeños");
        cb3 = new JCheckBox();
        cb3.setBackground(new Color(244, 244, 244));
        cb3.addItemListener(cL);

        panel_unten.add(panel_bilder, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel_bilder.add(bildbehälter1);
        panel_bilder.add(zutaten1);
        panel_bilder.add(cb1);
        panel_bilder.add(bildbehälter2);
        panel_bilder.add(zutaten2);
        panel_bilder.add(cb2);
        panel_bilder.add(bildbehälter3);
        panel_bilder.add(zutaten3);
        panel_bilder.add(cb3);

        // ------------------- Label Preis Extra Zutaten -------------------------------------

        panel_preis = new JPanel();
        panel_preis.setBackground(new Color(230, 0, 4));
        lab_total = new JLabel("IN DEN WARENKORB FÜR " + preis + " €", JLabel.CENTER);
        lab_total.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13));
        lab_total.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        panel_preis.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel_unten.add(panel_preis, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel_preis.add(lab_total);

        // ---------------------- Panel Button Bestellen --------------------------------------

        panel_button = new JPanel();
        panel_button.setBackground(Color.white);
        button_bestellen = new JButton("JETZT BESTELLEN");
        button_bestellen.setForeground(Color.white);
        button_bestellen.setBackground(Color.gray);
        button_bestellen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 40));

        panel_unten.add(panel_button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel_button.add(button_bestellen);

        button_bestellen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }


    class BotonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();


            if (cmd.equals("single")) {
                preis = 11.50;
                lab_total.setText("IN DEN WARENKORB FÜR " + preis + " €");
            }
            if (cmd.equals("jumbo")) {
                preis = 16.50;
                lab_total.setText("IN DEN WARENKORB FÜR " + preis + " €");
            }
            if (cmd.equals("big")) {
                preis = 26.50;
                lab_total.setText("IN DEN WARENKORB FÜR " + preis + " €");
            }

            if (e.getSource() == cb1) {
                System.out.println("Extra 0.90 €");
            }
        }
    }

    class CheckListener implements ItemListener {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            if (cb1.isSelected() && cb2.isSelected() && cb3.isSelected()){

                lab_total.setText("IN DEN WARENKORB FÜR " + (preis + (3 * extra) + " €"));

            } else if ((cb1.isSelected() && cb2.isSelected()) || (cb1.isSelected() && cb3.isSelected() || (cb2.isSelected() && cb3.isSelected()))){

                lab_total.setText("IN DEN WARENKORB FÜR " + (preis + (2 * extra) + " €"));

            } else if (cb1.isSelected() || cb2.isSelected() || cb3.isSelected() ){

                lab_total.setText("IN DEN WARENKORB FÜR " + (preis + extra) + " €");

            } else {

                lab_total.setText("IN DEN WARENKORB FÜR " + preis + " €");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

He intentado esto

```
 class CheckListener implements ItemListener {

        int numIngred = 0;
        int ingred1, ingred2, ingred3;

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            if (cb1.isSelected()) {
                ingred1 = 1;
            }
            else if (cb2.isSelected()) {
                ingred2 = 1;
            }
            else if (cb3.isSelected()) {
                ingred3 = 1;
            } else {
                numIngred = 0;
            }
            this.setPreis();
        }

        public void setPreis() {

            numIngred = ingred1 + ingred2 + ingred3;

            if (numIngred == 1) {
                preis += extra;
            }
            else if (numIngred == 2) {
                preis += (2 * extra);
            }
            else if (numIngred == 3) {
                preis += (3 * extra);
            }
            lab_total.setText("IN DEN WARENKORB FÜR " + preis + " €");
        }
```

Comment: Si todos los extras cuestan lo mismo, solo tienes que contar cuantos están activos y multiplicar el número de activos por el precio de cada extra y sumar eso al precio total. No hacer ifs con todas las combinaciones. Eso cada vez que cambie el estado de uno.

Comment: Gracias, ya he intenetado poner un contador pero quizas no lo hago bien y solo me funciona la primera vez que marco las casillas, pero si las desmarco y las vuelvo a marcar ya no funciona.

Comment: Publica el código modificado y tratamos de ver por qué solo te funciona una vez

Comment: Pues la verdad es que lo borre todo porque cada vez se estaba complicando mas y no funcionaba nada. La idea era una variable contador a la que llave numIngredientes = 0, cada vez que se marcaba la casilla se incrementa en 1 el valor del contador para cb1, cb2 y cb3. Luego programe un metodo con if-else q segun el valor del contador pues escribiera en el label el precio total del pedido. Luego lo meti en un bucle while e hice un monton de variaciones que ni me acuerdo. No se si me he explicado lo suficiente. Hace 3 meses que emoece a progrmar y es mi primera pregunta aqui, lo siento.